# Reading RAM from SH1106 OLED Controller through I2C

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, display

<sub>*Summary: I'm having trouble with writing a program to get RAM data from an SH1106 OLED controller via i2c. In the first part of the question I've written the assumptions I've made to get informations I couldn't find in the datasheet, in the second part I've posted a program which should read that data but doesn't (obviously, since I'm writing here...).*</sub>

I'm working on a program to control an SH1106 OLED display. I read the datasheet to find out how to send commands to it and it works, I can write to my display.
Now in the datasheet there is one thing I don't understand: how can I read the RAM?

Consider the picture below, taken from the command table at pages 30 and 31 of the [SH1106 datasheet](http://www.allshore.com/pdf/SH1106.pdf); the last line is the one about reading RAM.
This chip can be connected to a microcontroller through different interfaces: 6800 and 8800 8-bit parallel, 3 and 4 wire SPI and i2c. Since I'm using SPI I don't have any `A0`, `RD` or `WR` pin, and I didn't found anywhere in the datasheet a "translation" of the boolean value given to those signals in the command table to some i2c signal. I assume that WR corresponds with the lsb of the i2c address, since it is 0 for writing and 1 for reading. And my assumption seems to be true since I can read the status (line 25).
Then I assumed that `A0` should match `DC` (Data/Command, see second screenshot), a bit of the Control byte. The control byte is a byte that has to be sent before each byte or group of bytes to tell the chip how to interpret it (command or data). But I tried to send it before an i2c reading with different values and I always get the status byte (never the RAM data).

How could I read the memory of an SH1106 chip through i2c? The datasheet doesn't states that it is impossible (neither that it is possible...), maybe I simply can't?

**Command table**
[image: Command table]
(I removed lines 1-16, which contain commands like those at lines 17-23)

**Control byte**
[image: Control byte]

---

**EDIT**

Here is the shortest working program I could write which shows the problem (i.e. which contains my implementation errors). I tested it on an Arduino UNO.

```
#define ADDR  0x78


void i2c_start() {
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWSTA) | (1 << TWEN);
  while (!(TWCR & (1 << TWINT)));
}

void i2c_stop() {
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN) | (1 << TWSTO);
}

void i2c_send(uint8_t data) {
  TWDR = data;
  TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN);
  while (!(TWCR & (1 << TWINT)));

}

uint8_t i2c_read(bool isLastByte) {

  if (isLastByte) TWCR = (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN);
  else TWCR = (1 << TWEA) | (1 << TWINT) | (1 << TWEN);
  while (!(TWCR & (1 << TWINT)));
  return TWDR;
}


void display_init() {
  i2c_start();
  i2c_send(ADDR);
  i2c_send(0x00); //................ control byte
  i2c_send(0xAE); //................ displayOff
  i2c_send(0x8D); //................   *
  i2c_send(0xD5); i2c_send(0x80); // clockFrequency
  i2c_send(0x32); //................ pumpVoltage0123
  i2c_send(0xA1); //................ segmentRemap
  i2c_send(0xC8); //................ flipVertically
  i2c_send(0xDA); i2c_send(0x12); // comConfiguration
  i2c_send(0xA8); i2c_send(0x3F); // multiplex
  i2c_send(0xD3); i2c_send(0x3F); // displayOffest
  i2c_send(0x10); i2c_send(0x00); // columnAddr
  i2c_send(0x40); //................ startLine
  i2c_send(0xB0); //................ pageAddr
  i2c_send(0xAF); //................ displayOn
  i2c_stop();
}


void setup() {

  // Initialization
  Serial.begin(115200);
  display_init();

  // Request RAM data
  i2c_start();
  i2c_send(ADDR);
  i2c_send(0x80); //   control byte
  i2c_send(0xB0); // page address
  i2c_send(0x80); //   control byte
  i2c_send(0x10); // column address high
  i2c_send(0x80); //   control byte
  i2c_send(0x00); // column address low
  i2c_send(0x40); //   control byte
  i2c_send(0xE3); // nop
  i2c_stop();

  // get RAM data
  uint8_t a[10];
  i2c_start();
  i2c_send(ADDR + 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) a[i] = i2c_read(false);
  a[9] = i2c_read(false);
  i2c_stop();

  // print results
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Serial.print("0x");
    Serial.println(a[i], HEX);
  }

}

void loop() {}
```

I've tried as many possibilities as I could imagine in the `// Request RAM data` section. To avoid confusion I leave only the posted one to your kind analysis, but of course if someone would like to see them just write it in a comment and I'll post all the (unsuccessful) test I have made.

The output on the serial monitor is always a list of `0x3`s.

I've not reduced the initialisation routine I use in my code because maybe the issue comes from there. BTW, I have no idea about what the `i2c_send(0x8D); //................   *` line does, I've added it because all the others SH1106 libraries I found had it, but I didn't found it in my datasheet. Maybe there are multiple versions of the chip or of the datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

My version of the data sheet has a flowchart (Figure 10) for doing a "read-modify-write".  In there is a clue - there has to be a dummy read before the actual read is done.  Here is my function for plotting a pixel, which requires a read-modify-write to add a pixel to the existing data.  It's not clear dummy read is needed before every byte read, or just on the first of a sequence of bytes, but that's easy enough to test.

```
#define CTRL_LAST_CMD 0x00
#define CTRL_NEXT_CMD 0x80
#define CTRL_LAST_RAM 0x40
#define CTRL_NEXT_RAM 0xC0


void MySH1106_PlotPixel(char x, char y, char on) {
  unsigned char curDisp;
  MySH1106_SetPage(y/8);
  MySH1106_SetCol(x);

  Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDR);
  Wire.write(CTRL_LAST_CMD);
  Wire.write(0xE0); //R-M-W enable
  Wire.endTransmission(1);

  Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDR);
  Wire.write(CTRL_LAST_RAM);
  Wire.endTransmission(1);

  Wire.requestFrom(SLAVE_ADDR, 2, 1);
  while(Wire.available()<2);
  curDisp = Wire.read(); //dummy read
  curDisp = Wire.read(); //real read.  

  Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDR);
  Wire.write(CTRL_LAST_RAM);
  if (on) {
    Wire.write((0x1<<(y%8)) | curDisp);
  } else {
    Wire.write(~(0x1<<(y%8)) & curDisp);
  }
  Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDR);
  Wire.write(CTRL_LAST_CMD);
  Wire.write(0xEE);//end R-M-W
  Wire.endTransmission(1);

}
```

This is woefully inefficient for plotting one pixel, but it's a start.

Edit: I've subsequently confirmed that only 1 byte of dummy read is needed, even if the reads are stopped/restarted.  As long as you're only doing RAM reads, no further dummy reads are needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly tricky understanding the protocol with I2C.  The bit to watch is:

> If the R/ W bit is set to one in the slave-address, the chip will output data immediately after the slave-address according to the D/C bit, **which was sent during the last write access.** If no acknowledge is generated by the master after a byte, the driver stops transferring data to the master.

So you have to set the D/C bit in the transaction *before* you want to access the RAM.

It's unclear from the datasheet if you have to send a data byte after the control byte for it to be accepted, but if you do you can use the NOP command.

So you do a write of NOP with D/C (which, yes, corresponds to A0 in the other interfaces) set to 1 in the control byte (i.e., write the bytes 0x40 0xE3) and then you can do a read which should return the RAM contents at the current page/column address, which will auto-increment for each subsequent byte.

It's quite an unclear datasheet when it comes to explaining how I2C reading works...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tested it (in particular I hadn't considered using a NOP after the `0x40` control byte), but I'm still unable to read the data. I've edited my question adding the shortest code I could write which still contains and shows the problem.